# How to reduce/merge one-to-many relationship dataset into another dataset as one column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to Spark and Stackoverflow, and trying to figure out this question, not sure if my subject is describable. Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

I have two dataset, one just have ID, look like this:

```
ID
111
222
```

Another one contain ID, parent_ID, and Role, where parent_ID is linked to the ID in the previous table,

```
ID      Parent_ID      Role
444      111           Editor
555      111           Manager
666      222           Editor
```

What  I want to produce is a dataset like this:

```
ID   isEditor   isManager
111   True       True
222   True       False
```

What I originally think is join two tables by id/parent-id, and then reduce/merge multiple row into one, but have trouble with reduce/merge part.

Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the first table at all? Can't you group on parent_id and go from there?

Comment: The first two tables are the dataset I have from csv files. It contain some other columns but not related to my question, so I didn't mentioned them

Comment: So, for this question, you don't actually need the first dataset. Is that correct?

Comment: I need it, the dataset want to produce will need to contain all other columns that I didn't mentioned. to rephrase my question, it would be I will need to add two more columns to my first dataset: "isEdittor" and "isManager", the values of columns (True or False) is based on the data in the second dataset.

Comment: Yes, of course. But for this question it seems the focus is on how to add those two columns. The join itself is not that interesting, correct? Otherwise more information is necessary, i.e. what happens when ids exist in the first dataframe but not the second and vice versa. As the question currently looks, it can be solved using only the parent_id and role columns of the second dataset, which makes the first dataset unnecessary (hence I'm asking why you need the join).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by only using the second dataframe, the first one is not necessary. Using the same data as in the question:

```
val df = Seq((444, 111, "Editor"), (555, 111, "Manager"), (666, 222, "Editor")).toDF("ID", "Parent_ID", "Role") 

val df2 = df.groupBy("Parent_ID").agg(collect_list($"Role").as("Roles"))
  .withColumn("isEditor", when(array_contains($"Roles", "Editor"), "True").otherwise("False"))
  .withColumn("isManager", when(array_contains($"Roles", "Manager"), "True").otherwise("False"))
  .drop("Roles")
```

Which will give the desired result:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
|Parent_ID|isEditor|isManager|
+---------+--------+---------+
|      222|    True|    False|
|      111|    True|     True|
+---------+--------+---------+
```

The solution start with aggregating a list for each `Parent_ID` containing all possible roles. Then the `isEditor` and `isManager` columns is set to true or false depending on whether the roles are in the list or not using the built-in `array_contains` method. Finally, the temporary `Roles` column that contained the list of roles is dropped.

Comment: Worked smoothly! Thanks!!